# Nozzle Z-level is not aligned with Z-probe

Tags: creality-ender-3, pla, bed-leveling, nozzle, z-probe

With my Ender 3 S1 the bed leveling z-probe level and the nozzle Z-level are not alligned. The nozzle is 0.77 mm higher than the bed leveling probe. I think this causes some problems I have:

- When printing the first layer in PLA -- either a G-code for bed level calibartion, or an actual print -- the first layer is not properly attaching plate.
- Because the probe and the nozzle are not alligned, and the probe is lower, the probe pulls the first layer along and messing up the print.
- If the first layer comes out relatively okay and the print can continue, the print has trouble completing because the probe constantly scrapes over the print. Sometimes the print completes, sometimes the probe pulls the print loose from the bed during the scraping and print fails.

My question is, how do I align the Z-level of the bed leveling probe and the nozzle?

I would think there is some mechanism to align them.

Some notes.

1. The Z-offset moves both the probe and the nozzle.
2. I have tried replacing the nozzle thinking the nozzle might be damaged. But the difference remains.
3. I have measured the 0.77 mm at the center, but at all sides of the build plate I see a clear space between the pin and the nozzle.
4. Manually bed leveling does not work because after leveling on the nozzle the z-probe again adds the 0.77 mm space.
5. Printing TPU goes fine. I believe this is because the scraping of the TPU is less risky because the TPU flexes.

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue. The nozzle is supposed to be lower than the z-probe. It seems to be caused by some screws that were not fully tightened, and because of that the nozzle assembly was hanging over a bit. Now the z-probe and nozzle are exactly level. I suppose the z-probe can or should be higher than the nozzle. But exactly level is fine too.